# Canvas Animation run smoothy in Firefox but Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I recently try to play animation with HTML5 Canvas. I just do a simple animation like image transition from left-to-right. It's work okay in Firefox but in chrome, it drawn broken images, it's not smooth as draw in Firefox. This is my code:

```
    // Get the buttons.
var startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');

// A variable to store the requestID.
var requestID;

// Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('stage');

// 2d Drawing Context.
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Variables to for the drawing position and object.
var posX1 = 0;  
var pixelsPerFrame = 10; // How many pixels the box should move per frame.

// loading image
var image1 = document.createElement('IMG');
image1.src="http://www.activeennis.ie/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/child-swim-lesson.jpg";

var image2 = document.createElement('IMG');
image2.src="http://wallpapers111.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Desktop-Wallpaper-HD2.jpg";

var width = window.innerWidth - 5;
var height = window.innerHeight - 5;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

// Animate.
function animate() {
    requestID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // If the box has not reached the end draw on the canvas.
    // Otherwise swap the animation.
    if (posX1 <= width) {
        ctx.drawImage(image1, posX1, 0, width, height);
        ctx.drawImage(image2, -(width - posX1), 0, width, height);          
        posX1 += pixelsPerFrame;
    } else {
        posX1 = 0;
        var image3 = image1;
        image1 = image2;
        image2 = image3;
    }
}


// Event listener for the start button.
startBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Start the animation.
    requestID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
});


// Event listener for the stop button.
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Stop the animation;
    cancelAnimationFrame(requestID);
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hoangzinh/741g0u1j/7/

When I test that in Firefox it looks great, but Chrome has a lot of stuttering and tearing, for what seems a rather simple task.
Does anyone have a similar problem as me?

I'm using chrome version 40.0.2214.91 and Ubuntu version 14.04

Comment: Works fine on Chrome, exactly as the rest of browsers. What version do you have and what OS?

Comment: I'm using chrome version 40.0.2214.91 and Ubuntu version 14.04